# Need help understanding the meaning of the following sentence

Tags: multiple-negation, conjugations

*Unless neither John nor Harry eat the pancake, Andrew must eat it.*

Can someone help me understand the above sentence's meaning?

Comment: Where did you get this sentence? It's unnecessarily obscure. And it requires the singular verb **eats** after **neither**.  It seems to be trying to say that unless John or Harry eats the pancake, it's available to Harry.

Comment: @RonaldSole from a puzzle book. Plural verb **eat** is there after neither per the book.

Comment: I'm closing this question because it is about language designed to be difficult to understand for fun, so this is about a puzzle rather than a question about learning English.

Comment: But... for what it's worth, "unless" can be replaced with "only if not", then "not neither ... nor ..." can be replaced with "either ... or ...", so it means "If either John or Harry eats the pancake, Andrew must eat it (too)."

Comment: @gotube the puzzle is mathematical (reasoning based), not what you suggest. Please reconsider.

Comment: @chanzerre I agree, it's a reasoning-based puzzle, not a question about learning English. This site is only for questions about learning English. That's why I closed it. I even did you the courtesy of solving it. Not sure what else you want

Answer (score 3):

> ...neither John nor Harry eat the pancake...

John does not eat the pancake and Harry does not eat the pancake.

> Unless...

If the thing following does not happen.

So the sentence as written makes no sense. It states that Andrew must eat the pancake if either John or Harry has eaten it.

I would bet good money that the writer meant

> Unless either John or Harry eats the pancake, Andrew must eat it.

or equivalently

> If neither John nor Harry eats the pancake, Andrew must eat it.